# How do I fix the metainformation on the first commit in git?

Tags: git

This is a related question to [How do I edit git’s history to correct an incorrect email address/name](https://serverfault.com/questions/12373).  Using `git rebase -i <first commit>`, `git commit --amend --author "Foo <foo@example.com>"`, and `git rebase --continue`, I was able to fix the logs for all of the commits but the first one.  How do I fix the first commit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After much trial and error, the following recipe was found to work:

```
# tag the root-most commit so we can reference it
git tag root `git rev-list HEAD | tail -1`
# check it out on its own branch
git checkout -b new-root root
# amend the commit
git commit --amend
# now you've changed the commit message, so checkout the original branch again
git checkout @{-1}
# and rebase it onto your new root commit
git rebase --onto new-root root
# then nuke the temporary branch and tag we created
git branch -d new-root
git tag -d root
```

true credit should go to drizzd on #git for this answer.